# HTML5 - Symbols and Icons

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm using Font Awesome for a specific symbol, but for some reason the symbol is coming up as a box instead of what i wish. Can someone help me out?

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Home</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css2/style.css" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css" />    
    </head>     
    <body>    
        <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: something is wrong with your local `font-awesome.css` try using external
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
`

Comment: Tried that already but it still stays the same :(

Comment: Check your font file path

Comment: If you are using the local font-awesome stylesheet, you have to make sure you also have the fonts (ttf) present. Otherwise use the CDN version.

Comment: The Font file was missing. Cheers Guys, problem Solved ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check you font file path or otherwise you can call fontawesome file from cdn
Check updated snippet

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```